# What do I need to do to build a debug version of a VS2008 project and run it on a different computer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, runtime

We've been making release builds and running them on different servers for testing. We want some of these servers to have debug builds to make it easier to track down crash bugs.

When we try to make a debug build and run it on a different environment we get this error.

Activation context generation failed for "C:\SoundBetterMixer\SoundBetterMixer64_debug.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

My suspicion is that you have to build it on the machine that you're going to run it on, but maybe you can install a run time distributable? Is there more than that that needs to be done?

Comment: So did you "use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis", as the error text instructs? (The error tells you that it couldn't find a specific assembly for a specific architecture. Are you targeting AMD64? And, if so, are you attempting to run the app on an AMD64 platform?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install VC80CRT debug runtimes without full visual studio 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804589/how-to-install-vc80crt-debug-runtimes-without-full-visual-studio-2005)

Comment: @KenWhite we are going to try and run that program tomorrow. The release build runs on our processor, I know it's built for 64 bit.