# install VC++ Debug Runtime Distributable

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, runtime

Is there anyway to install or have VC++ Debug Runtime Distributable without installing Visual Studio ?
Just to run a dll that has been compiled in debug mode using VS2013 on another machine that hasn't VS2013.

Comment: When you deploy a .dll, you are supposed to use Release builds.  Why would you want to distribute a debug build?

Comment: this the specification they need

Comment: Its dll for credential provider and if windows succeds to load it , I should see "sign in options" when lock my device
but I see nothing 
that's why its failed !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install VC80CRT debug runtimes without full visual studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804589/how-to-install-vc80crt-debug-runtimes-without-full-visual-studio-2005)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For testing purposes, you can include the Debug DLLs you need 'side-by-side' with your application. You can find them on a machine with VS 2013 installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\Debug_NonRedist
```

When you deploy your app, you must use Release mode distributions. For Win32 desktop apps, use [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deploying-native-desktop-applications-visual-cpp) instructions. For Windows Store apps, you don't have to deploy the CRT as it's handled by the Windows Store.

Comment: thnxxxxxx I copy the dll msvcp120d.dll located at the path you specified  to system32 and its worked :)

Comment: I'd recommend copying it to the same directory as your executables on the test machine and not the System32 directory. Otherwise, it will be easy to forget that you 'hacked' the test system to get the debug build to work...

Comment: yea but actually my dll runs under system32 :)
I mean that my program is under system32 :)

Comment: It's not a good practice to put any file in the windows folder. You should deploy your software in a better place perhaps a folder inside of the Program Files.

Answer (score 3):

OP was asking about 2013, but the title is general, so..

I just wanted to point out that in newer Visual Studio releases with the "select what you want" installer, for the debug runtime you need just "tools" or "build tools" (e.g. `VC++ 2017 version 15.9 v14.16 latest v141 tools` or `MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ Build Tools`, not to be confused with the *toolset*)

As for where you can find the libs, VS 2015 still has them basically in the same path outlined in Chuck's answer. From 2017, you should have something like:

```
<root>\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.16.27012\debug_nonredist
```

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2022:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.36.32532\debug_nonredist\x64\Microsoft.VC143.DebugCRT
```