# Missing Dependencies with Qt Build on Separate PC

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

I am building a Qt App but I am having problems when I move the app to another PC. When I run the .exe the it keeps saying it is missing dependencies and once I transfer the missing one another one pops up. I assume that I need to install something on the target pc that contains all of these DLLs.

```
Some of the missing dependencies so far:
MSVCP140D.dll
vcruntime140d.dll
api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll
```

I think that there may be issues with the install of MSVS or MSVC on my build pc as I constantly have to point to things like UCRT manually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved? I am curious about Qt build issues.

Answer (score 0):

***Missing Runtime***: Those files are obviously part of a runtime that your application needs ([Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685) - maybe?), but more than that you seem to have distributed the debug version of your application which will depend on debug versions of runtime dlls (dll name ends with `"d"` as in MSVCP140**D**.dll). These are generally only installed on developer PCs, and are not for distribution to client PCs at all.

---

***Release Build***: Maybe try to build your application in **release mode** and try to run that executable on your client systems. The required runtime might already be present on their boxes, just not in debug version.

***Static Linking***: I suppose you could also try **static linking** (for the Microsoft runtime: [How do I make a fully statically linked .exe with Visual Studio Express 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398/how-do-i-make-a-fully-statically-linked-exe-with-visual-studio-express-2005)), if that is available to you (I am not up to speed with Qt's handling of this in terms of availability of static linking with different forms of licensing): [MSVCP140.dll missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998902/msvcp140-dll-missing). Just so it is mentioned: thought conceptually the same, static linking is different for Qt (licensing issues?) and the core Microsoft runtimes (see link above). Use a binary dependency checker to investigate how dependencies have changed with new compilation settings.

***Remote Debugging***: If you need to make a test PC capable of running your application in debug mode (maybe for remote debugging  without installing all of Visual Studio): [Preparing a Test Machine To Run a Debug Executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/cpp/ide/preparing-a-test-machine-to-run-a-debug-executable).

***"Hacky"***: It seems here is another, "hackier" approach that I would not really recommend: [install VC++ Debug Runtime Distributable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383833/install-vc-debug-runtime-distributable). For other Visual Studio versions look for the `debug_nonredist` folder. **`Debug versions of an application are not redistributable, and debug versions of the Visual C++ library DLLs are not redistributable. Very important`**.

Comment: Thank you for this, it has confirmed my suspicions and i will get back once I have an answer